# HTMLCollection [] is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```js
rowGetter = i => {
    const row = this.state.estimateItemList[i];
    const selectRevison = this.state.selectedEstimate.revision;
    const rowLenght = this.state.estimateItemList.length;
    const changeColor = document.getElementsByClassName('rd') as 
    HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
    if (row.revision > selectRevison) {
        for (let x = 0; x < changeColor.length; x++) {
            row.changeColor.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            // changeColor.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //this is get error(Cannot read property 'style' of undefined)
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

I want to change the row color when the condition `row.revision > this.state.selectedEstimate.revision`. How can I prevent the change of `this.color`. However im not getting any error but row color is not changing and `changeColor : HTMLCollection []` is not get any items. it is always `undefined`. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You aren't accessing `changeColor` correctly, ie you aren't using the key/index

Comment: Without the accompanying HTML we won't be able to help you. Something tells me your selector is wrong.

Comment: what do you mean bro with accompanying HTML ? what should I add ?

Comment: @PatrickEvans can you give me a bit example please. im new in react

Comment: What is `const changeColor = document.getElementsByClassName('rd') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>` supposed to do? `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, so why not use `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName...)` and then just iterate using `.forEach` (or map using `.map`) like you would any other array?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks you reply bro. is HTMLCollection already an array ? and please give me a bit .forEach example. there is no more array.

Comment: NodeList, HTMLCollection are array like objects (has nothing to do with react). Meaning you access them like an array, ie `changeColor[x]`

Comment: @PatrickEvans what can i do bro change array list to object array ?

Comment: They are absolutely not arrays. NodeList and HTMLCollection are _live_ lists, meaning that if your document changes, they change along. As such, _they can change while you iterate over them_, which can break all kinds of things. So before you iterate, you need to get a stable list, which you use `Array.from()` for. But with all that said: why are you querying the DOM at all? If you're in react, your DOM is the _result_ of your react code, so the idea is to manipulate/check everything on the react side.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your reply bro i used `const changeColor = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("rd") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>);` but still changeColor [ ] is not get anything it is still empty

Comment: I would still recommend "not accesing the DOM". That information should already be wholly discoverable on the React side. Also, as a small tip more related to [the code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct): try to refrain from calling people bro. A decent number of people will consider it offensive (and for good reasons given what the word is associated with in North American culture).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this :

const changeColor = document.getElementsByClassName('rd');

instead of :

const changeColor = document.getElementsByClassName('rd') as 
    HTMLCollectionOf;

Comment: [ts] Generic type 'HTMLCollectionOf<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). i get this error

Comment: Please make sure page have class name "rd"